# Why does it hurt to accidentally gulp air while drinking water?

Tags: pain, gastroenterology, water, swallow-swallowing

Sometimes when I'm chugging water, I accidentally swallow a big gulp of air.

It's extremely painful.

As I understand it, water is less compressible than air and people inadvertently swallow air all the time while smoking, chewing gum, drinking, etc.

How is this any different?

Comment: I find this a strangely compelling question.

Comment: Where exactly do you feel the pain - in the throat, behind the sternum, in the stomach...and is it only at one point at the time? And just about 1 second, not like 4-5 seconds long?

Comment: see my comment below

Comment: This interests me because I have the same issue. I was searching for a possible answer when I came across your post. It is extremely painful and takes up to probably 20 seconds for the bubble to pass, sometimes to the point that I have to spit out the liquid that I was trying to drink.

Answer (score 1):

Occasional severe pain in the throat and chest after swallowing that radiates into the arms and feels like a heart attack (as mentioned in the question and one comment) fits the description of **esophageal spasm** ([WebMD](https://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/tc/esophageal-spasm-topic-overview#1)).

The pain may last only for few seconds or minutes to hours ([OESO Knowledge](http://www.hon.ch/OESO/books/Vol_4_Prim_Motility/Articles/ART208.HTML)).

The causes and risk factors are not well understood; they can include acid reflux, unusal anatomy, problems with intrinsic esophageal innervation, etc. ([Emedicine](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/174975-overview)). The pain can be triggered by hot or cold beverages or stress, for example.

One possible explanation: Swallowing air results in a different onset of the esophageal peristaltic wave than usually. In combination with an underlying muscle/nerve abnormality, this can trigger a muscle spasm.

Diagnostic procedures include an X-ray with barrium swallow, esophageal manometry, etc.

Various endoscopic or surgical procedures can help...

Related terms: diffuse esophageal spasm, nutcracker or jackhammer esophageus, odynophagia.